# VPN IP Bind Option for OSX?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, vpn, openvpn

This is an OSX specific question. I have been googling my a$$ off, looking at OpenVPN clients like tunnelblick and viscosity. Obviously I'd like to use tunnelblick, but I have no problem paying a couple bucks for viscosity if I must.

**Question:** Do either tunnelblick or Viscosity (or any OpenVPN gui for OSX) provide the option for ip binding? Or whatever you call the option that, when my connection to my VPN is down, I am disconnected from the internet completely?

(From what I can tell tunnelblick will alert you that your connection is down. Viscosity I know nothing about.)

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you're setup to "send all traffic over vpn" (`redirect-gateway def1`)

If so, when you disconnect, all routes related to *OpenVpn* should be automatically deleted, so that your prior network is restored (`net_gateway`)

However if you want to **Block Internet Access** after *OpenVpn* disconnects, there are several options.

One way is to route **default** to your **vpn_gateway** (ie 10.80.0.25 in the below example)

```
sudo route add default 10.80.0.25
```

This can be done with a *down script* or through Viscosity's GUI.

Other approaches to solve this problem can be found [here](http://www.thesparklabs.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=443)